# Is it possible to get array/CSE formulas to work with conditional formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am trying to get a CSE formula to work with conditonal formatting.  When using CSEs with cells, you hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, but it appears that this key combination doesn't register in the conditional formatting window.  The alternative option is to create a CSE formula in a cell and then use that cell's value in the conditional format formula, but I'd really like to get it to work with the conditional formatting formula itself.

Comment: I tried this a while back and wasn't able to get it to work either. I ended up doing as you said by putting the formula in another cell and referencing it in conditional formatting.

Comment: I believe that all conditional formatting formulas work as array formulas, so just enter the formula with enter.  [Link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cformatting.htm)

Comment: @gtwebb, you should post that as answer and I will mark it because I just confirmed that you're correct.

Comment: There is a bug in Excel 2007 whereby "array formulas" used in CF don't work when worksheet is re-opened (unless you go back into CF first) so it's sometimes worth avoiding formulas that require CSE, there's usually a way to do that - which particular formula are you using here?

Comment: @barryhoudini I am using 2010, not 2007.

Comment: absolutely - I was just making the point for others reading this who might be using Excel 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All conditional formatting formulas work as array formulas, so just enter the formula with enter.

[Link to source](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cformatting.htm)